# gcm server response value

Tags: php, google-cloud-messaging

Step1
my server send message to app device
response is success

```
{
    "multicast_id":7728707543791363238,
    "success":4,
    "failure":0,
    "canonical_ids":0,
    "results":[
        {"message_id":"0:1470905757075944%4d9f3641f9fd7ecd"},
        {"message_id":"0:1470905757075946%4d9f3641f9fd7ecd"},
        {"message_id":"0:1470905757075383%4d9f3641f9fd7ecd"},
        {"message_id":"0:1470905757075948%4d9f3641f9fd7ecd"} ]
}
```

Step2 
delete add form device(android)

Step3
my server send message to same device
response is success too

```
{
    "multicast_id":5618205143815724662,
    "success":4,
    "failure":0,
    "canonical_ids":0,
    "results":[
        {"message_id":"0:1470906000290483%4d9f3641f9fd7ecd"},
        {"message_id":"0:1470906000289946%4d9f3641f9fd7ecd"},
        {"message_id":"0:1470906000291651%4d9f3641f9fd7ecd"},
        {"message_id":"0:1470906000289948%4d9f3641f9fd7ecd"} ]
}
```

i think success->0 , failure->4 and

```
"result":[
    {"error":"NotRegistered"} 
    {"error":"NotRegistered"} 
    {"error":"NotRegistered"} 
    {"error":"NotRegistered"} ]
```

because since there is no App on device.

Deive Receive success.
Server Language : php
Device : android

I reading **Table 5. Downstream HTTP message response body (JSON)** in document (Ref : https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref), but i don't know problem...

Why did I receive the wrong **response**?

Can I get a "NotRegistered"?

I am careful where I look?

Comment: Have you tried following the [Try Cloud Messaging for Android](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start)? This will help you understand the flow for Google Cloud Messaging: Register to enable GCM, Send and receive downstream messages, Send and receive upstream messages. For each device, first get a registration token for Google Cloud Messaging from the InstanceID API. This token is used to identify the instance of the quickstart running on your device.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is working as intended. When you uninstall the app the token will eventually be invalidated however for some time invalid tokens will still be usable. If the app is not installed then even if the device receives the message it will never be passed to the app. Then eventually on the server side it will start to fail.

Comment: I knew immediately that judgment.
Thanks for your help.